# If the product of the principal diagonal elements of a 2by2 symmetric matrix isn't a perfect square, why is it not invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

This question is from the 2014 JEE Advance paper

According to the answer key, D is right aswell, however I have a counter example

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
1 & 5\\
\end{vmatrix}
$$
why is this wrong

I have learnt that every invertible matrix has a non-zero determinant, why is this wrong?

Picure of question:_[image]

Comment: Your example is an invertible matrix in which the product of the principal diagonal elements is not a perfect square. So I would say, the answer key is wrong. ...or: There is some additional assumption in the exercise that you did not state here.

Comment: I'll add a picture of the question for reference

Comment: Okay, something is very strange here. (C) should NOT be a correct answer since the matrix that consists only of 1s is NOT invertible (det=0), but satisfies (C) ...

Comment: @Cosine that's not a diagonal matrix

Comment: and for part (D): The statement is also not a correct answer. Take the matrix with first row (2,2) and second row (3,3). Then the matrix is not invertible (det=0), but the product of the entries in the main diagonal is 6 and not a square of an integer...

Comment: @Cosine That counterexample is not symmetric

Comment: OP note that the determinant of a matrix is only given by the product of the entries in the main diagonal when the matrix itself is diagonal.

Comment: @HoldenRohrer: Thank you, my mistake, I overlooked the words "diagonal" and "symmetric" ... Maybe I should go back to sleep and not comment any more ... Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You learned right! Every invertible matrix does have a nonzero determinant. In fact, a matrix is invertible if and only if it has a nonzero determinant.

The determinant for a $2\times 2$ matrix is $ad-bc,$ (in the special case of a *diagonal* matrix, the determinant of a matrix is the product of the main diagonal entries, but not in general) and in our case we are dealing with a *symmetric* matrix with *integer entries*, so $b=c,$ and $b$ is also an integer.

For (A) and (B) we can use the zero matrix as a trivial counterexample.

Then, on to the interesting components. Note that we only need to show these are *sufficient* conditions, that is that assuming one of them implies the matrix is invertible.

(C) the diagonal matrix with nonzero entries in the main diagonal.

a diagonal matrix means that $b=c=0,$ and nonzero main diagonal means $a\neq0$ and $d\neq0,$ so the determinant is $ad-bc = ad-0 = ad \neq 0.$

(D) the product of entries in the main diagonal is not the square of an integer.

The determinant is $ad-b^2,$ and we already know that $b$ is an integer (the matrix has integer entries), so $b^2$ is the square of an integer. and if $ad$ cannot be written as the square of an integer, then $ad-b^2$ is not zero.

Note that your stated counterexample doesn't actually contradict this because the matrix you have given us is invertible with determinant 9.

Comment: ah, I see, thanks!